# http: TLS handshake error from 10.244.0.6:36004: remote error: tls: bad certificate

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dapr

I try to deploy my project using Dapr + Envoy proxy to AKS, it works fine in Minikube but in AKS the sidecar-injector logs

```
http: TLS handshake error from 10.244.0.6:36004: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

and the sidecar container not inject into pod.

I've tried to disable mTLS or enable http routing when create cluster in AKS but nothing works.
Any advice for this case?
Thanks.